Trying to resume a different type of list when I've defined different enumerate lists
I've defined two new different lists, but I want to be able to resume the numeration of one in the other, the lists I've defined are:
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{cuestion}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[cuestion, 1]{label=C\thesection.\arabic*.,leftmargin=\parindent, rightmargin=10pt}


\newlist{pregunta}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pregunta, 1]{label= P\thesection.\arabic*.,leftmargin=\parindent, rightmargin=10pt}

I want to be able to use the same numeration for the \arabic* in both. I want to be able to do something like the following:
\begin{cuestion}[series=T0]
\item ...
\end{cuestion}

\begin{pregunta}[resume*=T0]
\item ...
\end{pregunta}

Which would result into the same as if you were to code something like:
\begin{enumerate}
\item[C0.1.] ...
\item[P0.2.] ...
\end{enumerate}


please provide an example that people can run, you have posted some fragments using non standard commands for which you have shown no definition which makes it very hard to answer. I would guess you are using the enumitem  package but you haven't mentioned it or tagged the question that way.

@DavidCarlisle. Sorry for not responding before, but I did define the commands in the first code block. Maybe I should have posted an MWE instead of redacting the question like I did, but I do believe they are defined.

No sorry your first code block was using undefined commands such as \newlist  (which are defined in enumitem package that you had not mentioned anywhere)

When starting list A, in order to resume the numbering from list B you can use enumitem's before key to set A's counter as the last value of B. So for example if you want to start a list pregunta and resume the numbering from the last cuestion, you can start the pregunta list with
before=\setcounter{preguntai}{\the\value{cuestioni}}

Here's a complete example.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{cuestion}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[cuestion, 1]{label=C\thesection.\arabic*.,leftmargin=\parindent, rightmargin=10pt}

\newlist{pregunta}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[pregunta, 1]{label= P\thesection.\arabic*.,leftmargin=\parindent, rightmargin=10pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{cuestion}
\item ...
\item ...
\end{cuestion}

\begin{pregunta}[before=\setcounter{preguntai}{\the\value{cuestioni}}]
\item ...
\item ...
\end{pregunta}
\end{document}

